# Log approximation

Tags: approximation

Can somebody help me with this approximation:

> as $m$ gets really large, $\dfrac{r}{m}$ gets really small and hence $\log\left(1+\dfrac{r}{m}\right) \sim \dfrac{r}{m}$.

I don't understand how did $\log\left(1+\dfrac{r}{m}\right)$ approximately equals to $\dfrac{r}{m}$? Please clarify.

Comment: This is accomplished by using the Taylor Series expansion for $\log(1+x)$ when $|x| < 1$.

Comment: @Matthew your deleted answer looks fine to me. Was there a need to remove it?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, but after I looked at it some more it felt more like a comment than an answer, since I just let $\log(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$ without much explanation. On top of that using big-O notation seemed presumptuous.

Answer (score 5):

The natural logarithm of $1 + r/m$ is defined to be the area under the curve $t\to 1/(1+t)$ between $0$ and $r/m$.

[image: Figure]

When $r/m$ is small, this region (shown in blue) is approximated moderately well by a rectangle of height $1$ and base $r/m$ (shown in gray underneath), whose area is $r/m$. The relative error in the approximation is no greater than the decrease in the value of $1/(1+t)$ over the region, which for small $t$ becomes arbitrarily close to zero.  That answers the question.

---

From the figure it is clear that the region is much better approximated by a trapezoid with vertices at the origin, $(x, 0)$, $(x, 1/(1+x))$, and $(0,1)$, where $x=r/m$. Its area is

$$x\left(1 + \frac{1}{1 +x}\right)/2 = x\left(1 - \frac{x}{2+2x}\right).$$

In the next figure, these two approximations are plotted (in red for the trapezoid, gold for the rectangle) along with a graph of $\log(1+x)$ (in blue) for smallish values of $x$.  There is scarcely any visible difference between the trapezoidal approximation and the logarithm. All three values converge to one another as $x$ approaches $0$.

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, consider the Taylor expansion of your term:

$$\log(1+x) \approx x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} \pm \ldots.$$

Now, if $x$ (which stands here for your fraction $\frac{r}{m}$) becomes small, you can well approximate your function by the linear term in the Taylor series.

**Edit:** I see this already mentioned in the comments to the original question... so I won't claim priority for this deep result ;-)

Comment: The error term for the 3rd degree Taylor expansion is $O(x^4)$, so it is an equality not an approximation

Comment: ok, thanks, it's pedantic, but correct. I made an edit.

Comment: Taylor series approximations are not useful--even when they are known to converge--without some estimate of their error. In this case an estimate is easy to come by for positive $x$ because then the series alternates, implying the error is no greater than the size of the next term that would have been used. Thus the error in approximating $\log(1+x)\approx x\ge 0$ is no greater than $x^2/2$. Since $\log(1+x) = -\log(1/(1+x)) = \log(1 + \frac{-x}{1+x})$, the error for negative $x$ is bounded by $x^2/(2(1+x)^2)$ and that, too, is very small compared to $|x|$ when $|x|$ is small.